# How to pause/resume/cancel an event in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, events, uitabbarcontroller, pause

I have an UITabBarController and sometimes in didSelectItem delegate I need to pause the event and present a popup. If user confirmed the event resumes and if not, event will be canceled. Here's my code:

```
class YC_TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var prevIndex: Int!
    var exitAction: (()->Bool)?

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        self.prevIndex = self.selectedIndex

        if self.prevIndex == 2 {

            guard self.exitAction != nil else {return}
            //pause
            let isExitAccepted: Bool = self.exitAction!()
            //if true -> resume
            //if false -> prevent from switching tab

        }

    }
}
```

How can I do that? Please Help

Comment: present a popup? Do you want to use UIAlertController? Or do you use custom popup?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I want to use custom popup

Comment: add a seperate code to your custom popup

Comment: The actual problem is how to pause and resume or cancel this event. My custom popup returns a Bool And it all happens in exitAction()

Comment: You can't "pause" the event.  If you have determined that you want to proceed with the tab switch simply invoke the superclass `didSelect` method. If you don't want to proceed then don't call the superclass method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should confirm to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in first view controller and `return false` if the desired view controller is selected in `shouldSelect viewController`. Then you should show your popup view. In popup view ok/confirm button you can change selected view controller of the `self.tabBarController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController is SecondViewController {
            //show alert
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    func popUpOkAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        if let secVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is SecondViewController }) {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = secVC
        }
    }
}
```

> If you want to perform this from multiple view controllers rather than
>   firstViewController you can confirm to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in
>   `YC_TabBarController` itself.